# Is there any reason for not showing the published accepted profiles in the invitation page on Careers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I think it would be nice to have a direct link to the profiles that were accepted and published via link or email. Since most likely is somebody that I know of (I'm not that popular to have gazillion followers) it would be nice to see their public careers page.

Here is a suggestion:

[image: accepted invitations list on careers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent suggestion!  We already do this.  If they make their profile public, that "Yes" will turn into a link to the profile (not the most obvious thing in the world, but it's there).  The fact that those two are not links means that they have not yet made their profiles public (and "Published" just means they completed their profile).

[image]

Comment: Nice! Status completed means.. there will be a username more visible so you'll know what to expect without checking the status bar on hover?

Comment: '"Published" just means they completed their profile' - On the editing side, the interface only lists your own profile as "published" if you've actually made it public though, otherwise it's "hidden", so this seems a bit inconsistent. I'm not entirely sure what it would make sense for it to say instead, however.

Comment: @TimStone we're going to change it so we only show "Yes" under Published if the profile is public and linkable